# Why does my profile show one less badge than I have earned?

Tags: support, badges

I earned 23 badges in my Stack Overflow account, 17 unique badges and 6 revival badges. The total is 23 badges but the problem is that it shows 22 badges. Why?

Comment: What did you think the number next to the silver dot meant, out of curiosity?

Comment: 1. yellow dot represents gold badges. 2. gray dot represents silver badges 3. brownish dot represents bronze badges. Hand hover on those dots.

Comment: Or even, the **gold** dot represents **gold** badges, etc :)

Comment: That is an epic fail for ummm.... failing. At basic math. Personally I want my badge count in hex, imagine the trouble that would cause when it came time to sum them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have 22 [*bronze* badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=bronze) and one [silver badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=silver). Total 23.

[image]

Comment: Free hand writing wins! Guess Agnes had a blonde day and missed that extra silver badge in the profile, lol.

Comment: i am such a stupid to ask this question.it did not notice me  before asking question here.i am so sorry

Comment: @Tahmina: It's OK, we all make mistakes :)